# Show a link to all files in a folder with Razor code

Tags: c#, file, razor

I want to Show a link to all files in a folder. How do you do that in ASP.NET Razor code in WebMatrix. You can show all entries in a database with an

> @foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))

but I'm not sure how to do that by pulling all files from a folder.

Comment: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

Answer (score 2):

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) will give you list of files in given directory.

Note: beware of security issues exposing and accessing files in ASP.Net environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by the example shown below

```
    @foreach(var fileName in Directory.GetFiles("."))
    {
           .....
    }
```